# Minecraft malfunctions with a low enough Y-value?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing in the void with Minecraft when I suddenly realised that my `Y` gradually stopped working (exact value:`Y=-36 028 797 018 963 968`, can't really find the exact value). See this video:

First the decimal places start to stop updating. Then the whole `Y` co-ordinates update starts to slow. Then finally it freezes there and sometimes I get a lag spike. Why is this happening? What is the explanation behind this? Is the data too big to handle? Is my computer too slow to handle?

Comment: you went outside world bounderies.

Comment: Of course I AM. But the Y is gradually slowing (sorry I have now edited the question) to stop instead of just stopping at one point. First the decimal places start to stop functioning, then the `Y` co-ordinates update slows down, and then it freezes.

Comment: because you cant go there and it just won't let you fly any further. You just don't see that your not moving because you are in the void

Comment: But I can still teleport myself even further. And I can move, by the way. I can still go down, without Y updating. Why I know I'm moving? Because I see the sky moving up and down when I press and release Shift.(Sorry, I don't really understand your point...)

Comment: Someone smarter than me can confirm my suspicion that this is some kind of variable lenght limit on MinecrafT? The number is longer than a 32-bit Integer variable, and far too low for a 64-bit int, any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because computers store numbers in limited precision.

With bigger numbers the precision gets worse and worse, because the numbers are stored something like 1.2345·10<sup>123</sup> (but in binary... it's a long story).

Here, I try to decrease a big floating point number by different amounts. Notice how changing it by smaller amounts doesn't do anything.

```
>>> a = -360287969785042688.0
>>> a = a-1; format(a, 'f')       
'-360287969785042688.000000'
>>> a = a-5; format(a, 'f')       
'-360287969785042688.000000'
>>> a = a-10; format(a, 'f')  
'-360287969785042688.000000'
>>> a = a-15; format(a, 'f') 
'-360287969785042688.000000'
>>> a = a-20; format(a, 'f')  
'-360287969785042688.000000'
>>> a = a-25; format(a, 'f') 
'-360287969785042688.000000'
>>> a = a-30; format(a, 'f')  
'-360287969785042688.000000'
>>> a = a-35; format(a, 'f') 
'-360287969785042752.000000'
>>> a = a-35; format(a, 'f')
'-360287969785042816.000000'
>>> a = a-35; format(a, 'f')
'-360287969785042880.000000'
>>> a = a-35; format(a, 'f')
'-360287969785042944.000000'
```

Notice how the difference between numbers isn't actually 35. It is the smallest possible difference between two such huge numbers in binary floating-point representation.

The same happens in the game. Multiple times per second it tries to decrease your Y position by vertical speed, which is apparently less than this minimal difference between two neighboring numbers.

But if you teleport by a larger amount, you obviously can break that limit.

This is clearly outside the scope of this site. But there is plenty of information on [floating-point numbers](https://google.com/search?q=floating+point+numbers).

Comment: Ha! So my suspicions were correct, thank you sir, +1 to you :)

Comment: An active explination like i haven't seen before. Also yay for doing science with python interactive.